# Dynamic field definitions - can this be done in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, view

I have a requirement that I'm struggling to implement. If possible, I'd like to achieve this with native T-SQL.

I have the following tables:

```
CUSTOMER
========
ID,
Name

FIELDDEF
========
ID,
Name
FieldType   (Char  T, N, D   for Text, Number or Date)

CUSTOMERFIELD
=============
ID,
CustomerID,
FieldDefID,
CaptureDate,
ValueText,
ValueNumber,
ValueDate
```

Basically, the purpose of these tables is to provide an extensible custom field system. The idea is that the user creates new field definitions that can be a text, number or date field. Then, they create values for these fields in the ValueText, ValueNumber *OR* ValueDate field.

Example:

```
*Customer*
1,BOB
2,JIM

*FieldDef*
1,Mobile,T
1,DateOfBirth,D

*CustomerField*
ID,CustomerID,FieldDefID,CaptureDate,ValueText,ValueNumber,ValueDate
1,1,1,2011-01-1,07123456789,NULL,NULL
2,1,2,2011-01-1,NULL,NULL,09-DEC-1980
3,1,1,2011-01-2,07123498787,NULL,NULL
```

I need to create a view that looks like this:

```
*CustomerView*
ID,Name,Mobile,DateOfBirth
1,BOB,07123498787,09-DEC-1980
```

Note that Bob's mobile is the second one in the list, because it uses the most recent capture date.

Ideally, I need this to be extensible, so if I create a new field def in the future, it is automatically picked up in the CustomerView.

Is this possible in T-SQL at all?

Thanks,

Simon.

Comment: Please follow the formatting guidelines on the left side of the page to fix the formatting of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would not be possible with a view, unless the view is dynamically recreated on the fly every time `FieldDef` changes because view schemas are locked-in at creation time.  However, it may be possible with a stored procedure, which may or may not work depending on how you are using it.

**Edit 1**

Here is a sample query that works just for your current field names, and would have to be modified by dynamic SQL to work in general:

**Edit 2**

Modified to grab the newest values from the customer field table

```
with CustomerFieldNewest as (
    select
        cf1.*
    from
        customerfield cf1
    inner join
        (
            select
                customerid,
                fielddefid,
                max(capturedate) as maxcapturedate
            from
                customerfield cf2
            group by
                customerid,
                fielddefid
        ) cf2 on cf1.customerid = cf2.customerid
            and cf1.fielddefid = cf2.fielddefid
            and cf1.capturedate = cf2.maxcapturedate
)
,CustomerFieldPivot as (
    select
        C.ID as ID
        ,max(case when F.Name = 'Mobile' then CF.ValueText end) as Mobile
        ,max(case when F.Name = 'DateOfBirth' then CF.ValueDate end) as DateOfBirth
    from
        Customer C
    left join
        CustomerFieldNewest CF on C.ID = CF.CustomerID
    left join
        FieldDef F on F.ID = CF.FieldDefID
    group by
        C.ID
)
select
    C.*
    ,P.Mobile
    ,P.DateOfBirth
from
    Customer C
left join
    CustomerFieldPivot P on C.ID = P.ID
```

**Edit 3**

Here is T-SQL code to generate the view on the fly based on the current set of fields in FieldDef (this assumes the view `CustomerView` already exists, so you will need to create it first as a blank definition or you will get an error).  I'm not sure about the performance of all this, but it should work correctly.

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
declare @fielddef varchar(max)
declare @fieldlist varchar(max)

select
    @fielddef = coalesce(@fielddef + ', ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '') +
        '           max(case when F.Name = ''' + F.Name + ''' then CF.' +
            case F.FieldType
                when 'T' then 'ValueText'
                when 'N' then 'ValueNumber'
                when 'D' then 'ValueDate'
            end
        + ' end) as [' + F.Name + ']'

    ,@fieldlist = coalesce(@fieldlist + ', ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '') +
        '       [' + F.Name + ']'
from
    FieldDef F

set @sql = '
    alter view [CustomerView] as

    with CustomerFieldNewest as (
        select
            cf1.*
        from
            customerfield cf1
        inner join
            (
                select
                    customerid,
                    fielddefid,
                    max(capturedate) as maxcapturedate
                from
                    customerfield cf2
                group by
                    customerid,
                    fielddefid
            ) cf2 on cf1.customerid = cf2.customerid
                and cf1.fielddefid = cf2.fielddefid
                and cf1.capturedate = cf2.maxcapturedate
    )
    ,CustomerFieldPivot as (
        select
            C.ID as ID,
' + @fielddef + '
        from
            Customer C
        left join
            CustomerFieldNewest CF on C.ID = CF.CustomerID
        left join
            FieldDef F on F.ID = CF.FieldDefID
        group by
            C.ID
    )
    select
        C.*,
' + @fieldlist + '
    from
        Customer C
    left join
        CustomerFieldPivot P on C.ID = P.ID
'

print @sql
exec(@sql)

select * from CustomerView
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. The problem is that the table may contain up to 20 million customer records. So I don't want to create a SP to trawl through this each time. Is there a way to code the SP to avoid this?

Comment: WOW! That looks great. I'll test that out and come back to you. Recreating the query each time a new field def is created is not a problem. One other thing... does the max() function give me the latest mobile phone number or just the biggest alphabetically? I need the latest one based on CaptureDate

Comment: @Simon: I modified to filter out only the newest customer field values based on CaptureDate.

Comment: @Simon: I've added a code sample to create the view on the fly.  It assumes the view already exists, so you will need to create a blank view `CustomerView` before running, and it should keep it updated.  Not sure about the performance of all this, it may be slow.  Do you have your customer field tables indexed well?

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a crosstab which you do with the Pivot statement in TSQL. Here's an article that talks about how to build the pivot dynamically.

http://sqlserver-qa.net/blogs/t-sql/archive/2008/08/27/4809.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I will take a look at the article.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness there is [`sql_variant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181071.aspx):

```
 declare @t table (typ varchar(1), yuk sql_variant)
   insert @t values ('d', getdate())
   insert @t values ('i', 1234)
   insert @t values ('s', 'bleep bloop')

 select
    yuk, 
    case typ 
        when 'd' then convert(datetime, yuk, 106)+50
        when 'i' then cast(yuk as int) * 2
        when 's' then reverse(cast(yuk as varchar))
        else yuk
    end
 from @t
```